# Websocket not working in React.Js production build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, backend

I created a react App which talks to a node back-end. Everything works fine in development mode. The connection between the front-end and back-end is made through websocket.

Most interesting thing is, that after doing yarn build to create the production build of the app, all the pages work fine. The only thing is that, the page that integrates connection with the back-end is returning error when I inspected it in the browser. I am using Apache Server to run the build version of the app on localhost.

I am using Apache server since python server throws errors on page refresh.

Below is the screenshot. As you can see, node server command, return the expected response from the backend app. The structure of the app is also shown; revealing the relationship between the front-end (smartschool and smartresult) and back-end (smartapi). Only the smartresult makes the request to back-end. How do I resolve this connection problem? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It is now 4 days I posted this, yet, no response.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I added this as an issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12266